# Textblock not retrieving new style on property changed

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, styles, themes

I am using Silverlight 5 and trying to do some style binding to a viewmodel. I'm running into an issue with my binding not setting the new value when the property changes. But this only happens with the default style, if I use a key then it works correctly. Here are some examples.

**This works:**

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ForegroundBrush, Source={StaticResource Theme}}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,15,0,4"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
</Style>
```

**This Doesn't work:**

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ForegroundBrush, Source={StaticResource Theme}}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,15,0,4"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
</Style>
```

In the first example when the PropertyChanged event is called it rebinds the foreground color to the correct value. In the second example it doesn't rebind.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can remember, Style is always declared with x:Key property, and if you want to set some style as default for TargetType, use BasedOn property. Like...

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ForegroundBrush, Source={StaticResource Theme}}"/>
    ...
</Style>

<style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Should Try This way:**

```
 <Style x:Key="HeaderTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ForegroundBrush, Source={StaticResource Theme}}"/>
        ...
    </Style>

    <style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}" />
```